# How to invert direction of brackets (for a right to left text) in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, arabic, hebrew, right-to-left

The Unicode Bidirectional algorithm mandates that the glyph for the character "left parenthesis" (and many others) be inverted when displaying text in RTL direction.

However I am trying to typeset in ConTeXt a text in hebrew and parentheses appear incorrectly, )like this(. What can I do to invert them in the typesetting engine (I mean, without having to change the characters in the original text)? This question was asked before, but for LaTeX and XeLaTeX. I would need a solution for ConTeXt Mark IV

I attach a minimal working example:

```
\definefont[hebrewfont][arial at 12 pt]
\starttext
\textdir TRT
\hebrewfont
שלום (אני) כותב\\
\stoptext
```

Comment: Are you asking "Why doesn't this work as expected" or "How can I get it to typeset what I need, given how it works"?

Comment: @einpoklum Good question, I'd like to know "how I can get it to typeset what I need, given how it works".

Comment: There are some examples for bidirectional typesetting at the end of [``typo-dir.mkiv``](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/HEAD:/tex/context/base/typo-dir.mkiv#l82). Btw. ``\enableregime`` is unnecessary and should be removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper, high level, commands for setting text direction in ConTeXt are `\setupalign` and `\setupdirections` (they are “experimental” though).

```
\definefont[hebrewfont][dejavusans at 12 pt]
\setupalign[r2l]
\setupdirections[bidi=global]
\starttext
\hebrewfont
שלום (אני) כותב\\
\stoptext
```

For my personal work I use the [`context-bidi`](https://github.com/khaledhosny/context-bidi) module (wrote myself, even more experimental).

Comment: How do install the cotext-bidi module you mentioned above, when using Tex Live 2015 ?